# Regex to prevent multiple values for currency

Tags: regex

Wrecking my head and cant seem to get it right!

I am using the following created regex: `^([1-9][0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$)|^([1-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$)|(^[^0]*0[^0]*)$`

I want the following to be accepted:

```
0.01 -> 0.99
1.00 etc.
```

Right now 09.99 works when i dont want it to, possibly more!

I dont want 00.00 or 01.00 as this will be used for making payments and will need to be in good currency format.

Can someone shed some light on my regex?

Thanks!

Comment: In what programming language? Because why would you use regex for this? Just try casting the string to a number, then test if that number is higher than 0.01.

Comment: @LukStorms That will allow `01.00`.

Comment: Your last condition says "accept any string containing exactly one 0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?!0\.00$)(?:0|[1-9]\d*)\.\d{2}$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^
  (?!0\.00$)        : negative look ahead, make sure we do not have 0.00
  (?:               : start non capture group
      0             : 0
    |               : OR
      [1-9]\d*      : 1-9 followed by 0 or more digits
  )                 : end group
  \.\d{2}           : dot and 2 digits
$
```

Comment: Hi @Toto,

Works a charm! Will put this to test and see but seems to be perfect. Good idea, appreciate the help!:)

Answer (score 0):

You only need two alternatives in your regexp. One for 2+ digits before the decimal, which requires that the first digit be 1-9. The second is for 1 digit before the decimal, it allows 0-9.

You can also take `^` and `\.[0-9]{2}$` outside the alternatives, since they're the same for both cases.

```
^(?:[1-9][0-9]+|[0-9])\.[0-9]{2}$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Kp6UFF/2)